# Trying to make empty <li> tags hide on page load

Tags: jquery, hide, element, show

My current code is:

```
<ul>
<li class="nav">
<-- uc tag with hyperlink that show/hides based on a code behind & user rights. --><br />
</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $('li.nav:empty').hide();       
</script>
```

The line elements automatically populate in the application based upon user rights. There are multiple instances of this type of link within the navigation.

This solution worked in a different application that I was working on, but for some reason isn't working on my current application.

The code above is only an example - not a direct copy and paste.  The BR tags are not present in the actual application nor is the filler text.

Comment: Do you receive any script errors?

Comment: Are you actually including all of those `<br/>` elements in the code, or is that an artifact of whatever you used to cut & paste the snippet?

Comment: You're missing a `!` if that is supposed to be a comment ?

Comment: Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AvzCw/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove the 
 from inside the li ..

Enclose your script in **DOM ready Handler**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $('li.nav:empty').hide();
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like his script is below the actual html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide li elements with no text, you can use this :

```
$('li.nav').filter(function(){return $(this).text().trim().length==0}).hide();
```

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/liste.html)

Answer (score 0):

> `:empty` Description: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

I think your `$('li.nav:empty')` is not empty as there are some text nodes.

You should probably write a filter.

```
$('li.nav').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).text()); }).hide();
```